# Creating tables from email outputs - what is the easiest way?

Tags: excel, email, csv

I'm new here, I hope my question will be clear enough. I have around 200 email messages with some text inside, an output from a contact form on my website.

```
Name: Lorem Ipsum

Email: something@gmail.com

Mailing List: Yes

Israeli artist: Ido B & Zooki

artist of the year: Avicii

The phenomenon of the year: Martin Garrix - Animals

Israeli Discovery of the Year Dance: Matierro

Selected songs: 10
1. Dimitri Vegas & Like Mike & Moguai Mammoth
2. Martin Garrix Animals
3. Offer Nissim & Asi Tal Breath (feat. Maya Simantov)
4. Robin Thicke feat. T.I & Pharrell Blurred Lines (JRMX Remix)
5. Tiesto Take Me (feat. Kyler England)
6. Scream & Shout will.i.am (feat. Britney Spears)
7. Yinon Yahel Reach Out (feat. Alon Sharr)
8. Ylvis The Fox
9. Zedd Clarity (feat. Foxes)
10. Zedd Stay The Night (feat. Hayley Williams)
```

I would like to arrange all the information inside (First name, last name, email, etc.) in a table.

What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: A table in what? excel, Access some other RDBMS?

Comment: Hi @xQbert , I relly don't care, as long as I will be able to sum up the results...

Answer (score 0):

Given that the mail formats could be different, the number of songs selected different, unknown, and values each different, I don't think there is an "easy" way to do this.  You could import each into an excel workbook and then use a pivot table to summarize the results. but this will require about 2-4 hours of manual activity.  in formatting the imports, and writing formula's to parse the data so a pivot could be generated.

Here's an example based on 1 sample data provided.
[image]

```
B2:B9 uses the following formula: =LEFT(A2,FIND(":",A2)-1)
c2:c9 uses the following formula: =RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(":",A2))
B10:b19 uses the following formula: =LEFT(A10,FIND(".",A10)-1)
c10:c19 uses the following formula: =RIGHT(A10,LEN(A10)-FIND(".",A10))
```

the differences come due to the uses of : vs . as deliminators.

In the future I'd avoid emails based on form data and write it to a consistent file format.  It's more work up front but it will save you time on the back end parsing data.